# Zxing library not displaying scanned result in fragment activity

Tags: java, android

I am using zxing library in my app...below code working fine in fragment and displaying result..problem is in launching fragment activity i added below code..
on that time its not displaying scanned result..can anyone tell me

```
    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.zing);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
           startActivityForResult(intent,0);


        }
    });

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");


            // Handle successful scan
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Content:" + contents, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();

        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

        }
        }
    else
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Fragment don't have onActivityResult so you where you create or attach the fragment with activity add there onActivityResult and other handle.

Answer (score 2):

try this, working for me

add this code in Main activity

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
                for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
                fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```